# WP-REST-API v2 ajax call for post details

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Version 2 of the Wordpress REST-API isn't returning enough needed detail. Doing a ajax get request for Wordpress post. Code is below. The post title, date, link and image are great. However, when I add in the date and author I get a ISO8601 formatted date ( just need a standard date: December 29, 2015, and the author is only the ID ( need the author name ). I'm loading more posts in on button click. I read in the docs it's possible to modify the request with an action ( http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/modifying/ ), but not advanced in php enough to know how to change the date and get the author name. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var loadMorePosts = function( e ) {                                                                                    

    e.preventDefault();                                                                                                

    $.ajax({                                                                                                           
        url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=2&filter[posts_per_page]=3',                                       
        success: function( data ) {                                                                                      

            $( data ).each(function( k, v ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                         

                // Check for data                                                                                      
                if ( v ) {                                                                                             
                    var excerpt = v.excerpt.rendered,                                                                  
                        title = v.title.rendered,                                                                      
                        author = v.author,                                                                             
                        date = v.date,                                                                                 
                        link = v.link;                                                                                 
                } else {                                                                                               
                    return;                                                                                            
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

            });                                                                                                        

        },                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

        cache: false                                                                                                   

    });                                                                                                                
}
```

Comment: To get the full author name and slug you'll probably need another request to the API: **/rest/wp-json/wp/v2/users/<id>**
You can use the v.author from the first response in the <id> placeholder.
For the date, you just need to use the [JS Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to parse it and convert it to whatever format you want, e.g: new Date(v.date).getFullYear();

Comment: Also [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/), may come in handy when you want to easily convert between date and time formats.